# Datagram coming from the "wrong" IP

Tags: java, networking

I have a Linux box with a virtual IP set up.  Here's part of the output from `ip addr`:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:1f:13:60:10:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 212.179.158.220/25 brd 212.179.158.255 scope global eth0
    inet 212.179.158.221/32 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::e61f:13ff:fe60:1034/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On this machine, I create a DatagramSocket bound to `new InetSocketAddress(port)`, which should bind to the wildcard IP.

The application then receives messages sent to either **212.179.158.220** or **212.179.158.221**, but when it responds the response is always seen as coming from **212.179.158.220**, whereas I'd like the remote address of the response to reflect the IP that received the original message.

I can create a socket for each IP and listen on both; that gives me the behavior that I want, but it means that if the virtual IP comes up while the app is running it will ignore messages sent to the VIP.

So, now that I've laid this out:  Is there a way to get the remote host of the response message to be the same as the one the original message came in on?  I wouldn't expect it to be automatic, since how should the socket know to connect this response with that message?  But perhaps there's a way to force it?

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `IP_PKTINFO` socket option, then use `recvmsg()` to recieve the datagram and provide a `msg_control` buffer, an `IP_PKTINFO` control message will be included with the recieved datagrams that contains a `struct in_pktinfo` structure:

```
struct in_pktinfo {
    unsigned int   ipi_ifindex;  /* Interface index */
    struct in_addr ipi_spec_dst; /* Local address */
    struct in_addr ipi_addr;     /* Header Destination address */
};
```

This control message tells you the local destination address.  You can then supply the same control message with the response, using `sendmsg()`, and the original destination address will be used as the source.